# How to call Grails web service remotely from different application

Tags: jquery, web-services, rest, grails, getjson

I have a web service method in my Grails application which renders data in json format.

```
def getCityListJson(){
    def cityList= City.list() as JSON
    render cityList
}
```

which is basically a controller action.

Now i want to call this method from my PHP application

I have tried in my php page using Jquery

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
         $("#geCity").click(function(){
             $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/city/getCityListJson',               
             function(data) {
                console.log(data)
              });
         });
     });
  </script>
```

but not getting any response..

i am new to web service concept.. what is the correct way of invoking web service?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are both app running on same domain (`localhost:8080`) or different?

Comment: What error do you have on your browser console?

Comment: Ajax JSON don't work across domains, you should use JSONP instead. or CORS

Comment: After reading your response to @Igor, if the apps are running on different domains, why are you making a call to "localhost", instead of the host running the webservice? [UPDATE] As Igor mentioned, you are probably looking for JSONP or similar...

Comment: If your grails action *is not* being called, then the URL in your jQuery callback is incorrect. If your action *is* being called but jquery is not returning json data, then you're running afoul of "Same Origin Policy" issues and need to use `JSONP`. In any event, this has nothing to do with what frameworks you are using (grails/php) and you may consider editing your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your success callback, you try to log `json`, which is not declared.

You've named your parameter `data`. Change this and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#geCity").click(function(){
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/city/getCityListJson',               
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If this dosn't log anything, check your communication with the webservice with firebug or something similar. So you could check whether the request was send correctly and if the server send a (JSON) esponse as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that the action is called? Did you checked firebug or added some debug logging within your _getCityListJson_ action?

Comment: I have tried calling _getCityListJson_ action within grails its working fine.. but when i call that method from outside (from Php app) action is not being called ..

Comment: Then you have an error within your jquery code. Is the _click_ callback is called? May a typo? Is the id of the element really _geCity_ or do you have _getCity_?

Comment: You say: 1) Your click callback is called correctly and 2) Your action returns JSON as expected from within your grails app but 3) you didn't get any response within your AJAX request. Correct? What about firebug debugging? Are you sure that the url is correct?